# how can we prove that sum of cosine can be sine function

Tags: trigonometry, summation

I got this equation in a research paper but I couldn't understand how it was calculated:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\text{cos}\left[ \frac{(\pi k/2)\left( 2n+1 \right)}{2N} \right]=\frac 12\frac{\text{sin}\left( \pi k/2 \right)}{\text{sin} \left( \frac{\pi k/2}{2N} \right)}$$

Could you please help me proving if that equality is correct or no?

Comment: On the left-hand side, $k$ is an indexing variable for the sum. On the right-hand side, $k$ is a physical variable in the expression. This makes me think there is something wrong with the equation..?

Comment: @FrankW Sorry, I edited it.

Comment: You will make it easier to understand and prove if you write $\theta$ for $\frac{\pi k}{4N}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician  I am sorry, it is $\pi k/2N$,  I agree with you about that simplification, but will that equation becomes correct?

Comment: See ["How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/409).

Comment: @Blue it seems different about mine above results !

Comment: @Sajjad: The results are equivalent. To match the other question better, substitute $n\to k$, $N\to n$, $k\to p$, and rewrite a little; this is what you want to show:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{p\pi}{4n}+\frac{p\pi}{2n}k \right)=\frac{\sin\dfrac{p\pi}2}{2\sin\dfrac{p\pi}{4n}}$$ Taking $d=\dfrac{p\pi}{2n}$ and $a=\dfrac{p\pi}{4n}=\dfrac{d}2$, the other question says that the result should be $$\frac{\sin(nd/2)}{\sin(d/2)}\cos(a+(n-1)d/2)=\frac{\sin(na)}{\sin a}\cos(na)=\frac{2\sin(na)\cos(na)}{2\sin a}=\frac{\sin2na}{2\sin a}$$ Substituting $a$ gives the desired result here.

Comment: @Blue thank you for your explanation, please put it as an answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of a formula given in the question ["How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/409) and proven in the answers.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos (a+k \cdot d) =\frac{\sin(n \times \frac{d}{2})}{\sin ( \frac{d}{2} )} \times \cos \left( \frac{ 2 a + (n-1)\cdot d}{2}\right) \tag{$\star$}$$

To match that notation, substitute $n\to k$, $N\to n$, $k\to p$ into the current relation, and rewrite a little. This is what the question is trying to show:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{p\pi}{4n}+\frac{p\pi}{2n}k \right)=\frac{\sin\dfrac{p\pi}2}{2\sin\dfrac{p\pi}{4n}}$$ Taking $d=\dfrac{p\pi}{2n}$ and $a=\dfrac{p\pi}{4n}=\dfrac{d}2$, relation $(\star)$ says that the sum should be $$\frac{\sin(nd/2)}{\sin(d/2)}\cos(a+(n-1)d/2)=\frac{\sin(na)}{\sin a}\cos(na)=\frac{2\sin(na)\cos(na)}{2\sin a}=\frac{\sin2na}{2\sin a}$$ Substituting $a$ gives the desired result. $\square$